# Python Gui not responding to database

Tags: python, user-interface, sqlite, tkinter

The purpose of this post is to determine the error within the code, I have spent countless hours trying to alter the code to see what the error is. I am trying to add a employee to a database through a python GUI (tkinter). Currently it is only inserting " " information, this is checked within our the def delete with a print statement. A similar problem I am having with def delete however the information in the tuple is not displaying in a listBox. Does anyone have a solution to why these faults are occurring?

```
def addEmp():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Add Employee")
    top.geometry("470x385")
    app = Frame(top)
    app.grid()

    firstName = StringVar()
    lastName = StringVar()
    address = StringVar()
    payRate = StringVar()
    inUnion = StringVar()
    paymentMethod = StringVar()
    grp1 = StringVar()

    firstNameLabel = Label (app, text = "First Name:", font = 15)
    firstNameLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    firstNameEntry = Entry (app, text = "", textvariable = firstName)
    firstNameEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    surNameLabel = Label (app, text = "Surname:", font = 15)
    surNameLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    lastNameEntry= Entry (app, text = "", textvariable = lastName)
    lastNameEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    addressLabel = Label (app, text = "Address:", font = 15)
    addressLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    addressEntry = Entry (app, text = "", textvariable = address)
    addressEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    payRateLabel = Label (app, text = "Pay Rate Hourly:", font = 15)
    payRateLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    payRateEntry = Entry (app, text = "", textvariable = payRate)
    payRateEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    salaryLabel = Label (app, text = "Pay Rate Monthly:", font = 15)
    salaryLabel.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    salaryEntry = Entry (app, text = "")
    salaryEntry.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    payTypeLabel = Label (app, text = "Work Type:", font = 15)
    payTypeLabel.grid(row = 5, column = 0)

    radio1 = Radiobutton(app, text = "Full Time (Monthly Salary)", value = 'Monthly', variable = grp1)
    radio1.grid(row = 6, column = 1)
    radio2 = Radiobutton(app, text = "Part Time (Hourly Pay per Week)", value = 'Weekly', variable = grp1)
    radio2.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
    radio3 = Radiobutton(app, text = "Commission", value = 'Commission', variable = grp1)
    radio3.grid(row = 8, column = 1)
    paymentOptionsLabel = Label (app, text = "Payment Option:", font = 15)
    paymentOptionsLabel.grid(row = 9, column = 0)
    radio4 = Radiobutton(app, text = "Mail to current address", value = "Mail", variable = paymentMethod)
    radio4.grid(row = 10, column = 1)
    radio5 = Radiobutton(app, text = "Held by Paymaster", value = "Hold", variable = paymentMethod)
    radio5.grid(row = 11, column = 1)
    radio6 = Radiobutton(app, text = "Directly Deposit into bank account", value = "Bank", variable = paymentMethod)
    radio6.grid(row = 12, column = 1)
    unionLabel = Label (app, text = "Union:", font = 15)
    unionLabel.grid(row = 13, column = 0)
    radio1union = Radiobutton(app, text = "Yes", value = '1', variable = inUnion)
    radio1union.grid(row = 14, column = 1)
    radio2union = Radiobutton(app, text = "No", value = '0', variable = inUnion)
    radio2union.grid(row = 15, column = 1)


    submitButton = Button (app, command = addEmpSubmit, text = "Submit", font = 15)
    submitButton.grid(row = 20, column = 3)

def addEmpSubmit():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name, address, in_union, pay_type, payment_method) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
              (str(firstName), str(lastName), str(address), str(inUnion), str(payType), str(paymentMethod)))
    connection.commit()

    if payType == "Weekly":
        c.execute("UPDATE employees SET pay_rate=? WHERE employee_id=?", (payRate, c.lastrowid))
        connection.commit()
    elif payType == "Monthly":
        c.execute("UPDATE employees SET monthly_salary=? WHERE employee_id=?", (monthlySalary, c.lastrowid))
        connection.commit()
    elif payType == "Commission":
        c.execute("UPDATE employees SET monthly_salary=?, commission_rate=? WHERE employee_id=?",
                  (monthlySalary, commissionRate, c.lastrowid))
        connection.commit()


def deleteEmp():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Delete Employee")
    top.geometry("470x385")
    deleteList = Listbox(app)
    deleteList.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    listItem = ""

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM employees")
    allEmp = c.fetchall()
    for line in allEmp:
        for item in line:
            print(str(item))
            listItem += str(item)
        deleteList.insert(END, listItem)

    connection.commit()
    empIDLabel = Label (app, text = "Please select an Emp ID:", font = 15)
    empIDLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    empIDEntry = Entry (app, text = "")
    empIDEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

    deleteButton = Button (app, text = "Delete", font = 15)
    deleteButton.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
```

Comment: Does this code actually run without an error message? Because I don't see how `addEmpSubmit` would know about `firstName`.

Comment: @CL. Sorry for the late reply, I got caught up with work. No there is no error messages when running the program however it input blank information into the database. firstName is originally created as a class variable therefor both function should just simply change the original firstName variable. Is this correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Read properly the documentation on [ControlVariables / StringVar](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html).
   The values you provide for `INSERT INTO` - queries are not the values of the entry widgets.

```
>>> name=tk.StringVar()
>>> name.set("First Name")
>>> name
<Tkinter.StringVar instance at 0x01EB4CB0>
>>> str(name)
'PY_VAR0'
>>> name
<Tkinter.StringVar instance at 0x01EB4CB0>
>>> name.get()
'First Name'
```

2. Please make sure you post **only** code samples that can reproduce your error on (at least) your system. As for this reason it is *very* hard to reproduce the issues you have got.
   Split your code up and debug it in smaller slices. Check the different components on their own (e.g. first the sql part with some dummy data **but** using variables, StringVars, etc.).
3. Do you receive any error messages? If so, please add them to your post so that we can see if you are struggling at a certain point. Something like - "my code is not working - why?" is hard to analyze if even possible with correct information.

Comment: If I do recall using tk. is for when the program is using a class. If so the program is not using a class but simply functions creating new toplevels and roots. There is no error messages when running the program however it inputs blank information into the database, which can be seen when printing the employee list however does not show within the sql editor.

Comment: so if I get you right, you are telling that inside the sql editor the data is just fine?

Comment: When adding an employee the employee data enter is all empty strings only within the program. Which is problem one as the information entered is not being collected and saved to the variables. In the SQL editor after adding an employee there is no change to the data, meaning no new employee with empty string appears

Comment: as mentioned above:
you use `str(lastname)`. lastname is a `tk.StringVar object`. StringVar objects are read by calling their `get()` function.
Your code sample has no `global` or class-related keywords. That means that every variable (and it's content) are garbage collected at the end of the function.
Possible workaround: use a class (`self` keyword) or use global variables (generally not recommended for that purpose)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification I understand what you are explaining. I have previously tried the .get() functions but that is without the class or global variables this is probably the result as to why the program is not working.